# How do I use Saxon to do multiple search/replace on values, in a way that's efficient

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon

I used saxon v9 to profile an XSL transformation which converts XML to JSON. The profiler tells me that the function which escapes certain characters takes about 70% of the total processing time. The conversion is important because otherwise the created JSON file will be invalid because of characters that break the strings.

```
java -jar saxon9he.jar -xsl:jsontransform.xslt -s:input.xml -o:output.json -TP
```

The "method" used to escape the values looks like this:

```
<xsl:template name="escapejson">
        <xsl:param name="string"/>
        <xsl:sequence select="replace(
                              replace(
                              replace(
                              replace(
                              replace( 
                              replace(
                              replace(
                              replace(
                              replace($string, '\\','\\\\'), 
                              '/', '\\/'),
                              '&quot;', '\\&quot;'),
                              '&#xA;','\\n'),
                              '&#xD;','\\r'),      
                              '&#x9;','\\t'),  
                              '\n','\\n'),
                              '\r','\\r'),
                              '\t','\\t')"/>
    </xsl:template>
```

I already received valuable suggestions from Rolf Lear @rolfl in [this other post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/97580/xsl-template-for-converting-xml-to-json) and cut down the number of replace calls:

```
...
replace( '\n|&#xA;','\\n'),
replace( '\r|&#xD;','\\r'),      
replace( '\t|&#x9;','\\t')
...
```

But unfortunately it fails to process the data within my time constraints. I compared the original form of the xsl with the modified one and the time spent is nearly equal.

Because the XSL runs on a software appliance I have not file level access to I need a solution for saxon 8 because this is the version that is supposed to be in use there. And I assume that integrating Java into the xsl is not an option because (but I have not tested this yet) that this is prevented by the appliance for security reasons.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All the strings you are replacing are single characters, and you can probably exploit this fact. I imagine that the majority of strings probably contain none of these special characters. Therefore the best approach might be to do an initial examination of the string to see if it does contain any of these characters before doing the replacement. This can be done efficiently using translate: if the following expression is true

```
$x eq translate($x, '\/"&#xa;....', '')
```

then no replacement needs to be done. With luck, this will reduce the number of strings to be processed fully to a tiny fraction of the total, so that the efficiency of the multiple replace no longer matters.

Another approach would be to recode the replace logic as:

```
string-join(
  for $c in string-to-codepoints($in)
  return
    if ($c eq XX) then "\\"
    else if ($x eq XY) then "\n"
    else if ....
    else codepoints-to-string($c),
  "")
```

Incidentally, I think that `replace(X, '\n', Y)` means exactly the same as `replace(X, '&#xa;', Y)` so it is redundant to do both.

You say you need to use Saxon 8. There was in fact a succession of releases from Saxon 8.0 to Saxon 8.9, with an enormous amount of development between them. I'm not going to check the records for you to see what features were introduced when.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I am no match for you when it comes to Xsl knowledge. So this question may be silly: when translate is able to replace the values why not use it directly ?

Comment: @Marged - translate does a 1/1 character match from the source to the replacement, not a 1/1 word match. As a result it is just a high-level filter to show values that are candidates for deeper inspection. A quick, candidate test, rather than a comprehensive replacement. If your replace expressions were single-character ones it would be different.

Comment: translate() replaces one character by zero-or-one characters. You need to replace one character by multiple characters.